# Google Talk alert sound

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-talk, alerts

Is it possible to change the alert sound when a new message arrives for Google Talk? My colleague and I both have Galaxy Nexus' running Jelly Bean and when either of us get a Google Talk message its very confusing! :)

I can't see a setting for it in Google Talk and it doesn't seem to use the "Default notification" sound that is set under Settings -> Sound -> System.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Google Talk app when I go into `Overflow menu | settings | {username}@gmail.com` I see a setting for "Notification ringtone" under "Chat Notifications". That's what you want, no?

(I'm still on Ice Cream Sandwich so it's conceivable that things are a little different.)